# Calculating a factorial using loops in Python3

Tags: python, loops, factorial

I am currently studying Software Development as a beginner and I have a task in my programming class to calculate and display a factorial using a loop. I've been given the pseudo-code and have to translate it into true code and test it in the REPL to make sure it returns the expected results.

I almost have it but I've run into two issues that I just can't seem to resolve.

1) The function is returning an extra line of "None" after the calculation and

2) The answer is displaying over multiple lines when I want it to display on a single line.

My current code (which does return the correct answer) is as follows:

```
def calcFactorial(number):
    factorial = 1
    print(str(number)+"! =", number)
    for count in range (1, number):
        if number-count > 0:
            factorial = factorial*number-count
            print("x", str(number-count))
    factorial = factorial*number
    print("=", factorial)
```

When I test, using 3 for example, the REPL returns the following:

```
>>> print(calcFactorial(3))
3! = 3
x 2
x 1
= 12
None
```

So I have the correct answer but with an extra line of "None" which I would like to remove (I believe it has something to do with the print function?) and I don't know how to format it correctly.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct answer? From my understanding of "factorial", `3! = 6` should be the answer.

Comment: Oh no, you're absolutely right. I'll need to look at the calculation again and see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to count down from `number` and multiply the numbers together. The problem you have is due to order of operations in `factorial*number-count`. Note that you can get also get the correct result by counting up from `1` and multiplying the numbers together. Using this approach will lead to much simpler code.

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing `factorial*number-count` to `factorial*(number-count)`. Just a simple BODMAS error on my part. But thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to remember it!

Comment: Yes, that does the job. Notice that you can also do `factorial*count` and get the same thing with less typing.

Comment: Alternatively, you can count down with `range(number, 0, -1)`. Then you don't need the subtraction in your calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `calcFactorial` function does not explicitly return a value, so it would return `None` by default, so `print(calcFactorial(3))` would always print `None`.

You should make the `calcFactorial` function return `factorial` as a result at the end:

```
def calcFactorial(number):
    factorial = 1
    print(str(number)+"! =", number)
    for count in range (1, number):
        if number-count > 0:
            factorial = factorial*number-count
            print("x", str(number-count))
    factorial = factorial*number
    print("=", factorial)
    return factorial
```

Comment: That's it! It returned an extra line of `12` instead of the `None`  but I was able to fix that by removing `factorial` from the final print statement.

Comment: @MrShiver It would be better to remove the `print()` when you call the function. Either the function should print everything by itself or it should return a value, not both.

Answer (score 1):

your function calcFactorial(3) prints already, so you shouldn't call it with

```
print(calcFactorial(3))
```

just call it with

```
calcFactorial(3)
```

without the print function.

you might think about calling the function `calc_and_print_factorial()` in order to make it clear, that this function does already the printing

Comment: Alternatively, the function can be modified to only return the calculated value and not print out anything (other than for debugging purposes).

Comment: agreed.
In fact in general it is good practice to separate the part of the code, that calculates the result from the port of the code that displays the result.

This allows you to reuse the calculating code even if you need it lateron in a web application or in a GUI application instead of a console application

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question:

> Blockquote
>   2) The answer is displaying over multiple lines when I want it to display on a single line.

You can fix it by using a single print statement:

```
def calcFactorial(number):
    factorial = 1
    string = str(number) + "! = " + str(number)
    for count in range (1, number):
        if number-count > 0:
            factorial = factorial*(number-count)
            string = string + " x " + str(number-count)
    factorial = factorial * number
    print(string + " = " + str(factorial))
```

This will give you:

```
IN: calcFactorial(3)
OUT: 3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6
```

On a side note: you might want to think of how to implement this recursively. Maybe that comes later in your class but this would be one of the first go-to examples for it.

Comment: For better performance it would be better to append the partial strings to a list and `''.join(lst)` in the last print line

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652125/7737346), you should choose between these built-in ways to print the "returned" value.

### First way:

```py
def calcFactorial(number):
    ... # <- Your function content
    return factorial
```

Then, call your function with a `print()` to get the **explicitly** returned value, as you can see in the `return factorial` line. [See this reference for more details](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```py
print(calcFactorial(3))
```

### Second way:

Having the same function definition with its `return` statement, just call the function with its instance statement:

```py
calcFactorial(8)
```

By default, python will print the returned value without a `print()`

### Third way:

Just call the function (without the explicit `return` statement, this will return a "None" (null-like) value by default), using the `print()` method. **Do NOT** use `print()` inside another `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have the correct answer but with an extra line of "None" which I would like to remove

You are printing the return value from your function. In this case, you haven't specified a return value with a `return` statement so the function automatically returns `None`.

To fix the problem, you should return a value from your function. Note that you don't need to call `print()` for final answer because the REPL already does this for you.

Note that the REPL will automatically print the return value for you, so you can just type `calcFactorial(3)` instead of `print(calcFactorial(3))`.

Additionally, you are not getting the correct answer. You should get `6` instead of `12`. It looks like you are trying to count down from `number` and multiplying each number together. You can get the same result by counting up from 1. This will lead to much simpler code and avoid the error.

If you want to understand why your code isn't doing the correct thing, look closely at `factorial = factorial*number-count` and think about the order of operations that are used to calculate the result here.

Comment: The REPL doens't print the value automatically if it's `None`. The problem is that he explicitly called `print()` when calling factorial.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the clarification. I edited my answer.